# How to use one array as keys for another array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

[image]

I have these two arrays and I want to output it like this:

```
{
 "PT": "100",
 "ES": "400",
 "FR": "550",
 "CH": "200",
 "BR": "400",
 "DE": "500",
}
```

How can I do that? Probably its simple but I can't figure out how to do this, also I searched on stackoverflow and I didn't find anything like this..

This is a project in React, I don't know if that matter.
Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like those are what we call *parallel arrays*: The element at index *n* of one array relates to the element at index *n* of the other.

That being the case, you can use a simple `for` loop and brackets property notation:

```
const result = {};
for (let index = 0; index < array1.length; ++index) {
    result[array1[index]] = array2[index];
}
```

Live Example:

```js
const array1 = [
    "PT",
    "ES",
    "FR",
    "CH",
    "BR",
    "DE",
];
const array2 = [
    100,
    400,
    550,
    200,
    400,
    500,
];
const result = {};
for (let index = 0; index < array1.length; ++index) {
    result[array1[index]] = array2[index];
}
console.log(result);
```

You can also use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) with [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) to create the object, but it's more complicated (though shorter) and involves temporary array objects:

```
const result = Object.fromEntries(
    array1.map((array1value, index) => [array1value, array2[index]])
);
```

Live Example:

```js
const array1 = [
    "PT",
    "ES",
    "FR",
    "CH",
    "BR",
    "DE",
];
const array2 = [
    100,
    400,
    550,
    200,
    400,
    500,
];
const result = Object.fromEntries(
    array1.map((array1value, index) => [array1value, array2[index]])
);
console.log(result);
```

---

Side note: In your output, you've shown the values `100`, `200`, etc. as strings, but they're numbers in your input. If you want them to be strings, just convert them as you go, like this:

```
const result = {};
for (let index = 0; index < array1.length; ++index) {
    result[array1[index]] = String(array2[index]);
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^−−−−−−−−−−−−−^
}
```

Live Example:

```js
const array1 = [
    "PT",
    "ES",
    "FR",
    "CH",
    "BR",
    "DE",
];
const array2 = [
    100,
    400,
    550,
    200,
    400,
    500,
];
const result = {};
for (let index = 0; index < array1.length; ++index) {
    result[array1[index]] = String(array2[index]);
}
console.log(result);
```

---

You'll get people pointing you at [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), but `reduce` is only useful when you're doing functional programming with predefined, reusable reducer functions. Otherwise, it's just an overcomplicated, error-prone loop where using an actual loop would be clearer and easier to get right.

---

In a comment you've asked:

> What If I want it do be like this? `[{     text: 'pt',     value: 100,   },   {     text: 'es',     value: 500,   }]` ?

To do that, you want to create an object for each entry in the array. You can create the array via `map`, and you can create an object using an *object literal* (`{text: "PT", value: 100}` and similar, but getting the values from the array):

```
const result = array1.map((text, index) => ({text: text, value: array2[index]}));
```

or using shorthand property notation for the `text` property:

```
const result = array1.map((text, index) => ({text, value: array2[index]}));
```

Live Example:

```js
const array1 = [
    "PT",
    "ES",
    "FR",
    "CH",
    "BR",
    "DE",
];
const array2 = [
    100,
    400,
    550,
    200,
    400,
    500,
];
const result = array1.map((text, index) => ({text, value: array2[index]}));
console.log(result);
```

I've left those `text` values in upper case, but if you want to make them lower case in the objects, use `.toLocaleLowerCase()` on them:

```
const result = array1.map((text: text.toLocaleLowerCase(), index) => ({text, value: array2[index]}));
```

Comment: So easy and I can't figure it out.. thank you a lot!! :)

Comment: What If I want it do be like this? `[{
    text: 'pt',
    value: 100,
  },
  {
    text: 'es',
    value: 500,
  }]` ? Sorry for wasting your time buddy but I'm really new on this..@T.J. Crowder

Comment: @HenriqueMota - No worries, I added to the end of the answer. :-)

Answer (score 3):

```js
const arr1 = [100, 200, 300]
const arr2 = ["PT", "AT", "CT"]
const obj = {}
arr1.forEach((item, index) => {
  obj[arr2[index]] = item
})


console.log(obj)
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the `result` constant there? Note that `forEach` always returns `undefined.`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.forEach` to loop through one array and then populate the object.

```js
const keys = ["PT", "ES", "FR", "CH", "BR", "DE"]
const values = ["100","400", "550", "200", "400", "500"]

const myObj = {}

keys.forEach((key,i) => myObj[key] = values[i]);

console.log(myObj);
```

Comment: Thanks for the time buddy! I'm using the for trick that @T.J. Crowder said, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
b= [1, 2, 3]
c = a.reduce((acc, item, index) => {
  acc[item] = b[index];
  return acc
}, {})
// {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a very simple loop:

```
const arr1 = ['key', 'key2', 'key3'];
const arr2 = ['val', 'val2', 'val3'];
const obj = {};

for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    obj[arr1[i]] = arr2[i]; 
}

console.log(obj);
```

This will result in an object like this:

```
{ 
    key: 'val', 
    key2: 'val2', 
    key3: 'val3' 
}
```